# Is it possible to continuously move Google Form Responses to another Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Form that is accepting responses and filling them into a Google Sheet 1.

I want Sheet 2 in the same file to continuously grab responses in certain columns of Sheet 1 and import them into Sheet 2. This Sheet 2 will serve as a viewable spreadsheet, or a spreadsheet that my code is compatible with (reordered a certain way, different column names, colored).

What command/equation can I use in Sheet 2 ("move_here") to pull those columns from Sheet 1 ("responses")?

[image]

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I think this question lacks a bit of clarification. There are multiple ways this could be done depending on what you want. @player0 has laid just a very few of the possibilities (all valid). Myself I would choose the `QUERY` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
={responses!A:Z}
```

or:

```
=FILTER(responses!A:Z; responses!A:A<>"")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(responses!A:Z; "select A,B,C,D"; 0)
```

or other 20+ possible formulae...